# In SSRS I enter a date parameter . How do a calculate a future date from that Parameter (say 120 days from it?)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have naught but a static XML file to provide me the following data:

Event

Start Date

End Date

I must display a subset of this data within a 120 Day range of the input Parameter (Usually defaulted to today() but, not always).

How can I code paramters for a date range? It looks so simple but, I have spent all day on it.

Comment: @skaffman: you edited out the bad tags, but they should have been pasted into the question as they gave relevance to what the actual question was :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a [Multivalued](http://en.csharp-online.net/Building_Reports_in_SQL_Server_2005%E2%80%94Working_with_Multivalued_Parameters) (drop down list) parameter with something like this

- Current
- Last Week
- Last Month
- Last Quarter
- Custom

(or what ever other phrases make sense to you)

And add a textbox parameter for the "custom" option if needed

In you query, resolve the value returned from the drop down parameter in your where clauses as a series of logical evaluations

Comment: This is a good range possibility. I was looking for something even simpler which is causing the headache. When the user enters the date parameter, I simply want the range to extend to the parameter PLUS(+) 120 days.

Comment: @James Polhemus: Yes. So what is the problem with that?

If they choose last month, you calculate last month from current date and last month - 120 day in you Where clause. How could this be any simpler for the user?

Answer (score 0):

make a StartDate parameter make it time/date datatype and set the default value to:

```
=CDate(Day(Now()).ToString() & "." & Month(Now).ToString() & "." & Year(Now).ToString())
```

make a EndDate parameter make it time/date datatype and set the default value to:

```
=DateAdd("d",120,Parameters!StartDate.Value)
```

add a where statment in the query and use `"between @StartDate and @EndDate"` to use the date range .

if you want the `EndDate` always to be 120 days later then the `StartDate` use the hide or internal option in `EndDate` paranmeter